# CFSchedule Coldfusion 10, repeatInterval can not exceed 24 hours (86400 seconds)

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

Biweekly schedule interval doesn't work any more on Coldfusion 10. Is there any work around?

We were using program, which is user it schedule the tasks dynamically. So cannot use some hard coded fix.

```
<cfschedule action="Update" 
    task="launch_#pgmid#_#ProgramPath#" 
    operation="HTTPRequest"
    publish="yes"
    path="#rootpath#"
    file="log/#ProgramPath#_#pgmid#_launch.htm" 
    url="#url#"
    startdate="#dateformat(launchdate,'mmm/dd/yy')#"
    starttime="#time#" 
    interval="1209600" 
    requesttimeout="180"
>
```

Comment: I guess it is the same for coldfusion 9 too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CF10 you can use the cronTime attribute of cfschedule to set pretty much any schedule you need (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d31851899e53a51353e870493-8000.html).

Alternatively, you could schedule two monthly tasks offset by two weeks.